# BATCH IF ELSE resolution query

Tags: windows, winapi, batch-file

Running windows 8.1, my goal is to have a program that checks what the resolution is on my main monitor, then depending if it's 1920x1080 or 1376x768 it runs one file or the other. I have a `.bat` file set up so far that will change an `.ini` for fast resolution changing, but I'm trying to automate it further.

EDIT:: 
I've changed it to this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%r in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^, screenwidth ^| findstr "1"') do set current_res=%%sx%%r
if "%current_res%" == "1920x1080" call /d Monitor.bat
if "%current_res%" == "1376x768" call /d Laptop.bat
```

But it's not running the second bat, which deletes the Game.cfg file and copies in the preferred one, then runs the launcher.

Comment: The `/d` is an invalid parameter for `call`.  try removing that

Answer (score 2):

use `wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth` to get the current screen resolution (from [LINK](https://superuser.com/questions/270718/get-display-resolution-from-windows-command-line))

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%r in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^, screenwidth ^| findstr "1"') do set current_res=%%sx%%r
if "%current_res%" == "1920x1080" call Monitor.bat
if "%current_res%" == "1376x768" call Laptop.bat
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'd upvote your answer if you'd reverse the two options (the second one is a more direct answer to the question asked, as `wmic` is part of Windows and doesn't require downloading additional software, which IMO means it should be the direct answer).

Comment: I just removed the 3rd party method since this is better anyway

Comment: +1 for the reference to the right obscure utility. What about multiple monitors? It seems that `wmic` reports on just one....

Comment: +1. Thanks again for the edit (and for being so receptive to constructive criticism). :-)

Comment: Great, I'll try this one in just a sec and report back :)